# how to fix IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getResourceServiceProvider(URI.createFileURI("dummy.aadl")) returning null value

Tags: xtext, emf

I am using AADL which is domain specific language created using Xtext and EMF. I am trying to use function IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getResourceServiceProvider(URI.createFileURI("dummy.aadl")) but it returns null. how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you did never called the doSetup method of the AADLStandalibeSetup (or however your language impl is called). It is used to register your language if you do not run in an OSGi equinox environment.

Comment: When i try to call Aadl2Standalonesetup.doSetup() i am getting error message "An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.osate.xtext.aadl2 (917)".